# Janela MDI JavaFX: como deixar um AnchorPane responsivo ao AnchorPane Pai

Tags: java, javafx, layout-responsivo

Quero saber como faço para deixar meu AnchorPane interno responsivo exemplo:
eu tenho um tela principal e nessa tela principal tem um botão de configuração.

Quando eu clicar nesse botão, abre outro AnchorPane dentro do AnchorPane principal. O problema é que, quando o AnchorPane interno é aberto, ele não fica do tamanho do AnchorPane pai, ou seja, se eu redimensionar o AnchorPane Principal, o AnchorPane que esta dentro dele não redimensiona junto, ele fica do tamanho padrão que esta no meu SceneBuilder.

Como posso fazer meu AnchorPane interno se redimensionar junto com o AnchorPane principal?

Esse é o código do botão que adiciona o AnchorPane interno

```
 @FXML
 private AnchorPane adicionarTela; 

@FXML
    public void abrirTelaConficuracao() throws IOException, Exception {
        AnchorPane a = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TelaConfiguracao.fxml"));
        adicionarTela.getChildren().add(a);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você não está setando as âncoras. No FXML, é só ir no SceneBuilder na seção Layout do AnchorPane filho:

[image: Âncoras]

Já no código (que é o seu caso), você terá que colocar as âncoras manualmente:

```
AnchorPane a = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TelaConfiguracao.fxml"));
adicionarTela.setTopAnchor(a, 0.0);
adicionarTela.setBottomAnchor(a, 0.0);
adicionarTela.setLeftAnchor(a, 0.0);
adicionarTela.setRightAnchor(a, 0.0);

adicionarTela.getChildren().add(a);
```

Comment: as âncoras do FXML eu já tinha setado mas agora a parte do código que você escreveu setTopAnchor e os outros eu não sabia eu fiz e funcionou do jeito que eu queria muito obrigado, agora tenho outra duvida como posso fechar o AnchorPane interno sem encerra a minha aplicação